Ceph faild to add osd node to a new ceph cluster (Error EINVAL: Traceback (most recent call last))
I'm deploying a Ceph cluster with 3 nodes on Ubuntu 24.04. Everything works fine until I add OSD nodes to the cluster.
Here are my steps:
First of all, unfortunately, I encountered a bug while installing Ceph on Ubuntu 24.04. Here's the bug:2063456 and its resolution.
Secondly, it works properly when I add hosts and managers using the following commands:
ceph orch host add node-01
ceph orch daemon add mon node-01
ceph orch daemon add mgr node-01

Thirdly, I clicked the upgrade in the web console to update Ceph from 19.0.x(dev) to 19.1.0(rc) successfully.
Screenshot1
Lastly, when I add OSD, the error comes out.
# way1: failed
ceph orch apply osd --all-available-devices

# way2: failed
ceph orch daemon add osd node-01:/dev/sdb

the Error Output:
root@node-03:~# ceph orch daemon add osd node-01:/dev/sdb
Error EINVAL: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/mgr_module.py", line 1862, in _handle_command
    return self.handle_command(inbuf, cmd)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 184, in handle_command
    return dispatch[cmd['prefix']].call(self, cmd, inbuf)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/mgr_module.py", line 499, in call
    return self.func(mgr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 120, in <lambda>
    wrapper_copy = lambda *l_args, **l_kwargs: wrapper(*l_args, **l_kwargs)  # noqa: E731
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 109, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/module.py", line 1311, in _daemon_add_osd
    raise_if_exception(completion)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 241, in raise_if_exception
    raise e
RuntimeError: cephadm exited with an error code: 1, stderr:Inferring config /var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/mon.node-01/config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 5618, in <module>
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 5606, in main
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 408, in _infer_config
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 323, in _infer_fsid
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 436, in _infer_image
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 310, in _validate_fsid
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 3335, in command_ceph_volume
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/__main__.py", line 917, in get_container_mounts_for_type
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/cephadmlib/daemons/ceph.py", line 412, in get_ceph_mounts_for_type
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/cephadmlib/host_facts.py", line 760, in selinux_enabled
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/cephadmlib/host_facts.py", line 743, in kernel_security
  File "/var/lib/ceph/318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc/cephadm.4f62db9ec06251340dad8e5363cbd737ad7a336a838dec3e7dce5319a8dc37fb/cephadmlib/host_facts.py", line 722, in _fetch_apparmor
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Screenshot2

For comparison, I reinstalled Ceph without upgrading, and everything works fine.
I'm sure the HDD on the OSD node is normal.
System information:

root@node-03:~# hostnamectl
 Static hostname: node-03
       Icon name: computer-server
         Chassis: server 
      Machine ID: dbf44e1ea4ce499f962a93325471fa3b
         Boot ID: 3962c0814ffb4f6dafb2b850a79da3c1
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS                
          Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-38-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Dell Inc.
  Hardware Model: PowerEdge R640
Firmware Version: 2.3.10
   Firmware Date: Thu 2019-08-15
    Firmware Age: 4y 10month 4w 

root@node-03:~# ceph orch host ls
HOST     ADDR            LABELS  STATUS  
node-01  10.148.250.250                  
node-02  10.148.250.249                  
node-03  10.148.250.248  _admin          
3 hosts in cluster
root@node-03:~# ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     318e75df-405e-11ef-8f77-ca15ac0e63bc
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            Failed to apply 1 service(s): osd.all-available-devices
            failed to probe daemons or devices
            2 mgr modules have recently crashed
            OSD count 0 < osd_pool_default_size 1
 
  services:
    mon: 3 daemons, quorum node-03,node-01,node-02 (age 3h)
    mgr: node-03.ttcvsv(active, since 3h), standbys: node-01.qcixwc
    osd: 0 osds: 0 up, 0 in
 
  data:
    pools:   0 pools, 0 pgs
    objects: 0 objects, 0 B
    usage:   0 B used, 0 B / 0 B avail
    pgs:     


Ceph version 19 is not stable yet, only a release candidate. If you want to have a stable release, use Reef (version 18.2.2, 18.2.3 will be releases soon). And you can also report a bug on https://tracker.ceph.com. I just created a small test cluster with 19.1.0 and it applied OSDs successfully. Did you properly wipe the disks before trying to add them?

The issue is related with this file: /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles
Probably you have an entry like this: MongoDB Compass (unconfined)
Ceph uses a regular expression to split by space an get the confinement state. So this case with two spaces fails.
Try the following:
sudo grep -E '.*\s+\.*\s+.*' /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles

You'll get the entries that makes ceph to fail.
The remove them using apparmor by looking the found entries inside the directory: /etc/apparmor.d. For example, for MongoDB Compass:
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/MongoDB_Compass


Thanks to everyone for opening the thread. Your inputs helped me quite a bit to understand the problem. Indeed a very annoying bug on which I already spent some hours on my life. :-)
I checked the bug tracker and the Ceph versions which became released: so until now the bugfix did not become released yet. But it is included in the v19.2.1 release version now, which is not ready yet.
The bugfix will also go into the v17 Quincy and v18 Reef versions, but the fix is still not assigned to any release version.
So the v19.2.1 is where the fix will become released first.
The workaround from Sive.Host put me on the right track. But actually after checking the official documentation, it's much easier to do:
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/MongoDB_Compass /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/MongoDB_Compass
sudo systemctl reload apparmor.service

Check that the MongoDB_Compass profile became disabled:
sudo systemctl status apparmor.service
sudo cat /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles | grep MongoDB


I had a similar issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and also with Ubuntu 24.04.
OSD addition was working, and all of the sudden it stopped working.
I installed LXD for managing containers, and the containers had the "MongoDB Compass" apparmor profile enabled.
root@ceph01:/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd# aa-status|grep -e ":.* .*"
   :lxd-ctdb1-1_<var-snap-lxd-common-lxd>:MongoDB Compass
root@ceph01:/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd# 

Just going inside the container and removing the removing the profile as it was suggested previously fixed  the issue.
root@ctdb1-3:~# sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/MongoDB_Compass
root@ctdb1-3:~# exit
logout
root@ceph03:~# aa-status|grep -e ":.* .*"
root@ceph03:~#


JUST A QUICK WORK-AROUND:
If on ubuntu 24 LTS, having ran apt full-upgrade on it to make ceph squid stable 19.2.0, and apparmor profile MongoDB Compass is the only profile with space in its name you can just do the following to work around this, especially on the node with the issue, but probably good to apply to all nodes for consistency.
#1 check profiles with spaces:
sudo nano /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles 

, do not edit, just read, do not mind the (unconfined), the space in between it and the profile does not count.
sudo systemctl disable apparmor

sudo systemctl stop apparmor;sudo systemctl status apparmor

sudo mkdir /etc/apparmor.d/disabled/

sudo mv /etc/apparmor.d/MongoDB_Compass /etc/apparmor.d/disabled/

Then reboot and check whether the issue is solved. If it is Not, probably wise to reverse the action by:
sudo mv /etc/apparmor.d/disabled/MongoDB_Compass /etc/apparmor.d/

And then the below you do either way, whether solved or not (unless you want to keep apparmor disabled and risk the consequences):
sudo systemctl enable apparmor
sudo systemctl start apparmor;sudo systemctl status apparmor

Then reboot and check whether everything is still functional.

I've also had this issue and hit a bit of a brick wall. This is a bug that seems to have been fixed, but for some reason the Ubuntu 24.04 noble-updates package for cephadm seems to potentially be an older version of Ceph(adm) 19.2.0. This package also unhelpfully returns its version as UNKNOWN
user@node:~$ sudo cephadm version
cephadm version UNKNOWN

Seems to me like there isn't really good support for Ubuntu 24.04 right now, and disabling apparmor profiles doesn't seem like a good option.
I don't want to have to rebuild to 22.04, but it doesn't look like I'm left with much choice. Yay for Ansible playbooks for build at least.
